# Express - Multiple angular apps

Tags: node.js, express

I have express hosting an angular application right now, and it works as it is supposed to. However, I was considering making a new app and hosting it at a different route. I could not get this to work - even on the route to the new app, the old app opens. I'm guessing it has something to do with the static files, but I couldn't solve the issue. Here's how I'm trying to implement it -

```
// ...
// The usual express code
// ...
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist'))); // for the original app
app.use('/admin/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../admin/dist'))); // for the new app
app.get('/admin/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../admin/dist/index.html')); // Serve the new app
}
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.htm;')); // Serve the old app
}
// ..
// The remaining code
// ..
```

The routes seem to be working fine when I use *res.send('something');*, but it serves the old page whenever I try to use sendFile. Is there any way to have multiple angular apps and serve them simultaneously?
I'm using angular4, and node v6.9.3

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same problem. Mine has the same behavior whether using the `get` functions or not

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to make this work.
In the index.html of the admin app, make the `base` tag like this

```
 <base href="/admin/">
```

My full html file looks is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Admin</title>
  <base href="/admin/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <apt-root></apt-root>
</body>
</html>
```